# Limit API for use on specific websites

Tags: php, api-design

So we have an open API for ZIP codes and would like it so only specified websites can use it. Currently we are using CORS in combination with keys to stop unauthorized websites from using it but there are some cases where that won't do anything. Since the API is used with Javascript the key is right in the Javascript as well.

How would I make this secure? It seems that no matter how I do it, people will be able to use it from other websites.

Comment: _no matter how I do it, people will be able to use it from other websites..._ Yes, they will. As long as they know your api key

Comment: So you're saying it's impossible to make this secure? @B001ᛦ

Comment: Create an AUTH Service using JWT and expiration.

Comment: @MarkusZeller Would that do anything in the end though? Users don't have to be authenticated on a site to use it so everyone would get the key anyways.

Comment: @K1ll3rM That's why I suggested using AUTH for API users. Then you can limit all you want.

Comment: @MarkusZeller Hmm alright, I'll read up on it.